# Can't make VBA click a link on IE

Tags: excel, vba

I have tried hundreds of options I found here and other websites and I was unsuccesful. Hope you guys can help me.

I am trying to CLICK a link in IE though VBA, but for some reason it is not working. My full code is here

```
Sub ExtrairPIB()

Dim IE As InternetExplorer
Dim html As HTMLDocument

Set IE = New InternetExplorer
IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate "http://www.cidades.ibge.gov.br/xtras/uf.php?lang=&coduf=12&search=acre"
Do While IE.ReadyState <> 4
DoEvents
Loop

Set html = IE.document

html.getElementById("m1200013").Click


End Sub
```

I am not experienced at this and I don't know if this is right. Here is what appears on the console

```
<div id="filtro_mun_letra" style="height: 23px; margin-top: -23px;">
<ul id="lista_municipios">
<li id="m1200013">
<a href="perfil.php?lang=&codmun=120001&search=acre|acrelandia">Acrelândia</a>
</li>
```

When the code runs the command line with click, it just does not happen anything.

Please help me guys

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not actually clicking on the link, just the list item that contains the link.

Change the last few lines to the following:

```
Set m = html.getElementById("m1200013")
Set a = m.getElementsByTagName("a")(0)
a.Click
```

Tested and working on my end.

Comment: If this answer helped you, kindly mark it as the accepted answer or upvite it by clicking on the check mark to the left of this post. This is how we say thanks in StackOverflow.